Solve $10^k\equiv 2^k\pmod{2^{k+1}}$ & $10^j+10^k\equiv 2^j+2^k\pmod{2^{k+1}}.\,$ Binary digits ends with its decimal digits (with at most two 1's)

Find all positive integers $n$ such that the binary representation of
$n$ ends with its decimal digits and contains at most two 1's in its
decimal representation.

Here is my current approach:
$$
n_{10} = \overline{a_1a_2\dots a_k}
$$
$$
n_2 = \overline{b_1b_2\dots b_l}
$$
Where $k= \lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor + 1$ and $l = \lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor + 1$.
I attempted to express this problem as:
$$
n_2 = \overline{b_1b_2 \ldots b_{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor - \lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor} a_1a_2 \ldots a_{\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor} a_{\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor + 1}}
$$
Writing it out, we have:
$$
a_1 \times 10^{\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor} + a_2 \times 10^{\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor - 1} + \dots + a_{\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor - 1} \times 10^1 + a_{\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor} \times 10^0
$$
$$
= b_1 \times 2^{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor} + b_2 \times 2^{\lfloor \log_2(n) - 1 \rfloor} + \dots + b_{\lfloor \log_2(n) - 1 \rfloor} \times 2^1 + b_{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor} \times 2^0
$$
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor} a_i \times 10^i = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor} b_j \times 2^j
$$
From here I am thinking of constructing some sort of relation between $a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_{\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor + 1}$ and $ b_{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor - \lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor + 1}, \dots, b_{\lfloor \log_{2}(n) \rfloor + 1} $ to draw out some specific conditions about the $n$ that satisfy the condition.
I am not really sure however how to do this and if this is fruitful approach at all.
So any help would be greatly appreciated!

What do you mean "the binary representation of $n$ ends with its decimal digits"?  Can you give some examples of the sort of $n$ you have in mind?  Note that the second condition just means that $n=2^m+2^k$ for some non-negative integers $m>k$, or that $n=2^k$ for some non-negative integer $k$.

What I mean is that $n$ in decimal form, will be present at the end of binary form of $n$. So for example for $n=10$ the binary form is going to be 1010, which contains digits $n$ in base 10 in its last two digits (of the binary form)

That seems quite arbitrary...what is the source of this problem?

Note: in my first comment I (incorrectly) used base $2$ for the second requirement.  All those $2's$ should have been $10's$.

It is a math olympiad style question I found among problems from a local high school math competion.

Hint: With Lulu's comment, you want to solve for $ 10 ^m + 10^k  \equiv 2^m + 2^k \pmod{2^{m+1}} $ and $ 10^k \equiv 2^k \pmod{2^{k+1}} $ Start factorizing, applying LTE, etc. What can you say from there?

The binary representation of $n$ ending with the decimal digits of $n$ means those decimal digits can only be $0$ or $1$. Since $n$ can only contain up to two $1$'s in its decimal representation, and it's positive, then there are $2$ main cases to consider, as Calvin Lin's comment hint suggests.
First, $n$ has just one $1$ in its decimal representation, i.e., $n = 10^{a} = 5^{a}(2^{a})$ for some integer $a \ge 0$, which is $1$ followed by $a$ zeros in decimal. In binary, it will be the binary representation of $5^{a}$ followed by $a$ zeros. Since $5^{a}$ is odd, its last binary digit is $1$, so all such values work. Alternatively, using Calvin's suggestion, $10^{a}\equiv 2^{a}\pmod{2^{a+1}}\;\to\; 5^{a}\equiv 1\pmod{2}$ is always true. For example, as your comment indicates, $a = 1$ gives $\color{blue}{10}_{10} = 10\color{blue}{10}_{2}$.
Second, $n$ has two $1$'s in its decimal representation. Then, $n = 10^{a} + 10^{b}$ for some integers $a \gt b \ge 0$. In this case, in binary going from the right to the left, $b$ digits will be $0$, then a $1$, then $a - b - 1$ more zeros, and then a $1$. For this to happen requires that, in binary, $5^b$ ends with a $1$, but with at least $a - b$ zeros to the left of that. This means that
$$5^{b} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{a - b + 1}} \;\;\to\;\; 2^{a - b + 1} \mid 5^{b} - 1$$
We also get this by using Calvin's suggestion of $10^{a} + 10^{b}\equiv 2^{a} + 2^{b} \pmod{2^{a+1}}$ which leads to $2^{b}(5^{b}-1)\equiv 2^{a}(1-5^{a}) \pmod{2^{a+1}} \;\to\; 5^{b}-1\equiv 2^{a-b}(1-5^{a})\equiv 0\pmod{2^{a-b+1}}$.
Note that $b = 0$ works for all values of $a$, i.e., $n = 10^a + 1$ (e.g., $\color{blue}{101}_{10} = 1100\color{blue}{101}_{2}$, as stated in Eric's comment). Otherwise, for $b \gt 0$, then using the Lifting-the-exponent lemma, if $b$ is even, we require
$$\nu_2(5^{b} - 1) = \nu_2(4) + \nu_2(6) + \nu_2(b) - 1 = 2 + \nu_2(b) \ge a - b + 1 \;\to\; \nu_2(b) \ge a - b - 1$$
For example, there's $a = 3$ and $b = 2$ with $\color{blue}{1100}_{10} = 1000100\color{blue}{1100}_{2}$, and $a = 4$ and $b = 2$ with $\color{blue}{10100}_{10} = 100111011\color{blue}{10100}_{2}$.
If $b$ is odd instead, then the condition is that
$$\nu_2(5^{b} - 1) = \nu_2(5 - 1) = 2 \ge a - b + 1$$
Since $a - b \ge 1$, the only case which works is where $a = b + 1$. For example, we have with $a = 2$ and $b = 1$ that $\color{blue}{110}_{10} = 110\color{blue}{110}_{2}$, plus $a = 4$ and $b = 3$ giving $\color{blue}{11000}_{10} = 101010111\color{blue}{11000}_{2}$.

To check, why did you write $ v_2(5^b - 1 ) = v_2 (4) + v_2(6) + v_2(b) - 1 $? Where did $v_2 (6) $ come from? $\quad$  My application of LTE is just $v_2(5^b-1) = v_2 (5-1) + v_2(b) $, so we agree on the same final value of $ 2 + v_2(b)$.

@CalvinLin The Lifting-the-exponent lemma Wikipedia article says that "If $2\mid x-y$ and $n$ is even, then $\nu _{2}(x^{n}-y^{n})=\nu _{2}(x-y)+\nu _{2}(x+y)+\nu _{2}(n)-1$". In my case, with $n=b$, $x=5$ and $y=1$, we get $\nu_2(5^b-1)=\nu_2(5-1)+\nu_2(5+1)+\nu_2(b)-1=\nu_2(4)+\nu_2(6)+\nu_2(b)-1=\nu_2(4)+\nu_2(b)$. As you stated, we get the same result because $\nu_2(6)=1$ cancels the $-1$ at the end of the formula.

Ah, my bad. I keep on forgetting that $p=2$ is a special case.

It seems to have gone unstated, but for every decimal $n$ ending in $0$ that fits the criteria, don't we also have $n+1$ fitting the criteria as well. For instance, $11_{10} = 1011_2$ and $101_{10} = 1100101_2$.

@EricSnyder For my second case, i.e., where $n=10^{a}+10^{b}$, I state "Note that $b=0$ works for all values of $a$". This is $10^{a} + 1$, i.e., basically the same as what you commented on.
